# How to store elements of a list of HTML tags fetched with BeautifulSoup within a dataframe separated in alphabetically columns with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I am completely new to Jupiter Notebook, Python, Webscraping and stuff. I looked and different answers but no one seems to has the same problem (and I am not good in adapting "a similar" approach, change it a bit so I can use it for my purpose).

I want to create a data grid with all existing HTML tags. As source I am using MDN docs. It works find to get all Tags with Beautiful Soup but I struggle to go any further with this data.

### **Here is the code from fetching the data with beautiful soup**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

get_nav_tag = soup.find("nav", class_="sidebar-inner")
get_second_div = nav_tag.find_all("div")[2]
get_ol = get_second_div.find("ol")
get_li = get_second_div.find_all("li", class_="toggle")[3]

tag_list = get_li.find_all("code")

print("There are currently", len(tag_list), "tags.")

for tags in tag_list:
    print(tags.text)
```

[image: Output of web scraping]

The list is already sorted.

### **Now I work with Pandas to create a dataframe**

```
import pandas as pd

tag_data = []
for tag in tag_list:
    tag_data.append({"Tags": tag.text})

df = pd.DataFrame(tag_data)
df
```

The output looks like

[image: Output of Pandas]

### **QUESTION**

How do I create a dataframe where there are columns for each character and the elements are listed under each column?

**Like:**

```
  A         B      C 
1 <a>      <b>    <caption>
2 <abbr>   <body> <code>
3 <article> ..    ...
4 ...      ...    ...
```

How do I separate this list in more list corresponding to each elements first letter? I guess I will need it for further interactions as well, like creating graphs as such. E.g. to show in a bar chart, how many tags starting with "a", "b" etc exists.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The code below should do the work.

```
df['first_letter'] = df.Tags.str[1]
tag_matrix = pd.DataFrame()

for letter in df.first_letter.unique():
    # Create a pandas series whose name matches the first letter of the tag and contains tags starting with the letter
    matching_tags = pd.Series(df[df.first_letter==letter].reset_index(drop=True).Tags, name=letter)
    # Append the series to the tag_matrix
    tag_matrix = pd.concat([tag_matrix, matching_tags], axis=1)    

tag_matrix
```

Here's a sample of the output:
[image]

Note that you might want to do some additional cleaning, such as dropping duplicate tags or converting to lower case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot` and `concat` methods to achieve this

```
df["letter"] = df["Tags"].str[1].str.upper()
df = df.pivot(columns="letter", values="Tags")
df = pd.concat([df[c].dropna().reset_index(drop=True) for c in df.columns], axis=1)
```

This gives
[image: output]